# Installing Graphviz & Dependencies without Internet access

Tags: rpm, aix

I am trying to install graphviz on AIX7.1 - I have NO internet access and I have downloaded a lot of rpm files.

I want to know is there a way to install the graphviz-*.ppc.rpm packages so that the installer will check in my /backup/rpm/ folder for any required/dependency packages? (Without me having to install every dependency packages 1 by 1)

ok it appears I am missing the X file sets on my Aix and I have NO internet access and NO nim server :(   Any way to get these file sets?

Comment: If you downloaded all the packages, can you not just install them all with `rpm -i *`? I am not familiar with `rpm` but I know that would work with `dpkg`...

Comment: I tried and did not work. I am not sure if I need to set some value so it knows to look in the directory

Comment: @AquaAlex what error did you get from `rpm -i *`?

Comment: error: failed dependencies:
        libX11.a(shr4.o) is needed by libXpm-3.5.10-2

Comment: error: failed dependencies:
        libxml2 >= 2.6.32-3 is needed by libcroco-0.6.5-1

Comment: Sounds like you don't have all the RPMs you need, or an RPM is not providing a library.

Comment: For other opensource packages, I can recommend http://www.bullfreeware.com/ as they offer to download a .zip file with all the dependencies for any package, and the versions they offer are often pretty recent, compared to all other parties offering AIX packages. Sadly they don't offer graphviz. 
For graphviz dependencies take a look at http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=main.graphviz - you seem to be missing at least some X and libxml packages. Keep in mind that for every items listed there below **Package dependencies** you also need to recursively get all the dependencies. Hope that helps.

Comment: @AquaAlex: Oh, and if that helps here's a good list for direct download - for AIX 6.1 can be used also under 7.1: http://bluefinch-nl.blogspot.de/2013/11/install-graphviz-on-aix-61.html
Only the last step for installation can be simplified to `rpm -ihv ./*rpm` if you have all the dependencies in one folder.

Comment: I like: http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.ListOfPackages

Comment: @doktor5000 Thanks will check, yes I spend hours finding dependencies :D

Comment: It appears I am missing the x filesets

Comment: Yep, mentioned that previously in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212079/installing-graphviz-dependencies-without-internet-access?noredirect=1#comment360560_212079

Comment: http://f9-preview.runhosting.com/adminsys.info/?p=88

Comment: it seems a lot of people struggle with similar issue because the dependencies lists all assume you have the X filesets installed :D  Which is a dangerous assumption on AiX